# essential matrix rotational angle

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

With the presence of the essential matrix, we can easily get the rotational matrix and translation matrix from it.

However, how can we get every angle of the 3D rotation from the rotational matrix?

Thanks very much for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean you want to extract Euler angles from a rotation matrix. It is possible to do that but you should know there are different representations (orderings) of Euler angles and once you choose one, you should stick to it in the rest of your project. By searching in Google I came up with the following links, but there are definitely more. However if you want to have a better understanding of Euler Angles, I've found Physics text books on the topics of Mechanics very useful.

[Source from Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html)

[Another good source](https://truesculpt.googlecode.com/hg-history/38000e9dfece971460473d5788c235fbbe82f31b/Doc/rotation_matrix_to_euler.pdf)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix#Determining_R_and_t_from_E

from this website, it teaches the method of extracting the rotation matrix. However, it is built by Rx*Ry*Rz or vice versa? i quite confuse about this.

Comment: This is why I didn't mention Wikipedia page. There are many representations, and if I remember correctly there is even an Rz*Ry*Rz representation in mechanics! So it's best to find a scientific source and setup your code around that structure. It's only a matter of representation and nothing else. But I think in computer science it is usually Rx*Ry*Rz.

Answer (score 0):

The book Graphics Gems IV has a beautiful implementation of this by the legendary Ken Shoemake.  It will convert from a rotation matrix to any of the 24 different different Euler conventions.  Code is available [on the Graphics Gems website](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/euler_angle/).  I've tested it in production under many conditions and have found it to be correct and efficient.